# Android Streetview - avoid indoor locations

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2, google-street-view

Is there any way to prevent the newly release Streetview for Android (as part of the Google Play Services SDK), from showing me indoor locations?

I want to set the position based on a LatLng and radius, but I only want outdoor locations.

Thanks,

Andy.

Comment: can u provide me link for newly release Streetview for Android.

Comment: I have used the google's Street view app to show the street view. I think this app will show only out doors locations

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.street

Comment: Here is a link to the SDK I'm referring to. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/streetview

Comment: Im trying the street view panoramo code. but i getting this error "StreetViewPanorama cannot be resolved to a type" how can I import the StreetViewPanorama in my project. please help

Comment: please can u answer this
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881905/streetviewpanaroma-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type

Comment: @AndrewKelly - 3 years later... Have you found a solution to to this? Cheers!

Comment: No, the feature request I raised with Google is still open without any response/action. You can star it here if you'd like. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35824536

Comment: Thanks @AndrewKelly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On March 20, 2018 Google finally announced that this feature was implemented.

> When setting the position of a Street View Panorama, you can now provide a StreetViewSource allowing the search to be restricted to outdoor-only results. Note this feature is experimental and some searches may still include indoor panoramas. For details, see the guide to Street View.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases#march_20_2018

The corresponding feature request in the public issue tracker was marked as fixed

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69047818

StreetViewPanorama now supports the following methods

`public void setPosition (LatLng position, StreetViewSource source)`

`public void setPosition (LatLng position, int radius, StreetViewSource source)`

Have a look at the documentation to get more details:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/StreetViewSource

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/StreetViewPanorama

Happy coding!