# StreetViewPanaroma cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, google-maps, google-street-view

I m referring the code official code of [Google maps StreetViewPanorama](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/streetview). but I m getting this always. ***StreetViewPanorama cannot be resolved to a type***.

How can I import this class.

I have added the Google Play service lib project. and also I have set my project target to Google APIs x86[Android4.4.2]

here is my project structure

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got the latest version of the Google Play Services library downloaded? You'll need version 4.4 to access the new StreetView classes.

Andy.

Comment: Thanks. It I deleted the old Google Play services and downloaded the latest from android SDK manager and it worked. thanks alot